# How can I solve this simple C function?

Tags: c, function

I am taking a hybrid class of "Algorithms, architecture, and assembly language" at my local community college. Although it's an intro class and mainly focuses on how computers turn code into binary, we have some assignments for C code. Some of the stuff we've never even gone over in class, and I'm lost.

The instructions read:

> Write a function named DoSomething, with no return value, it should do just one (1) thing: multiply the global variable my_result by 5 and store the result back into my_result
>
> You do not have to call DoSomething, or initialize my_result, I will do that.

I have  tried

```
int my_result;

dosomething (my_result) { 

    my_result = my_result * 5;

}
```

but this is incorrect. I have almost zero experience with C language and am stuck. I'm not asking anyone to do my homework, I just want to understand. This has not been covered in class.

Comment: Hint: `void dosomething () { /* what you have */ }`

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking related to the code. *Please help me solve this problem* is useless; you're posting here, so you clearly are asking for help with a problem, and *C code* is clear because you used a tag for *c*. Your title should contain enough information so it's useful in a list of search results seen by a future reader here.

Comment: And, I really should explain a bit further. Every function has a type (e.g. `int, int*, char, double*, etc..`). The type defines the type of value the function will return. If the function return nothing, then the type is `void`.l

Comment: By the way, the reason your version wasn’t working is that the function parameter `my_result` became a new, different variable that hides the global `my_result`, at least inside the function. There is a way to still get the global `::my_result`, but the real-world solution is simply not to do that. It just leads to confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You almost have it.  Since `my_result` is global, you do not need to pass it into the function, it is accessible everywhere.  Oh, and every function needs its return value specified.  Use `void` to specify that there is no return value and no parameters.

```
int my_result;

void dosomething (void) { 

    my_result = my_result * 5;
}
```

Comment: For style points you can explain `my_result *= 5;` In addition to `my_result = my_result * 5;`.

Comment: Yeah, but I generally hold off introducing new ideas that like to absolute beginners, they have enough to keep straight already.

Comment: Yep, it goes either way. If introduced, even it if doesn't stick, the next time around, he will at least have that "you know, I've seen that somewhere before.." feeling.

Comment: The `()` should be `(void)`. The former says that the function takes an unspecified number and type(s) of arguments, which is not particularly useful (it's in the language for historical reasons). `(void)` says the function takes no arguments, which is what you want.

Comment: @KeithThompson You beat me to it. To be pedantic, that only happens for a function *prototype*. Still good enough reason to just simplify it for a student. (Reference if you care: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p14)

Comment: (a) This is wrong because the assignment instructions say to name the function `DoSomething`, not `dosomething`. (b) The instructions do not say to define `my_result`. They are unclear on this, but it may be incorrect for the student to supply a definition, as it may be provided by the instructor. (Envision software that automatically takes the user’s submission and inserts into a program that already defines `my_result` and `main` and then compiles and runs the program.)

Answer (score 3):

A correct function declaration must have a type, the name of the function and its arguments.

```
type function_name(type1 arg1, type2 arg2, type3 arg3, ...);
```

If a function does not return anything, then `type` must be `void`

```
void function_name(type1 arg1, type2 arg2, type3 arg3, ...);
```

If a function does not take any parameter, then the you can use `void` instead
of the list of arguements:

```
type function_name(void);
```

Your `dosomething` function is missing the return type, which should be `void`
(assignment says *Write a function named `DoSomething`, with no return value*)
and it takes no arguments (at least the assignment does not specify any), so the
correct prototype of the function must be:

```
void DoSomething(void);
```

So the correct program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_result;

void DoSomething(void)
{
    my_result = my_result * 5;
}

int main(void)
{
    my_result = 6; // initializing global variable

    DoSomething();

    printf("my_result: %d\n", my_result);

    return 0;
}
```

which will print `my_result: 30`.

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone, I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the code compiler on the college's side. It is still saying incorrect, the frustrating thing is it gives me a hint template, and everything looks correct, except it asks me to name the function at the end. I really don't understand.

Comment: @Devin edit your question and post the exact error of the compiler. Please also add which compiler you are using.

Comment: The error message simply says "sorry, incorrect!" and then gives me a hint on how I am supposed to write it, which looks correct.  It's not an actual compiler I am using, its a drop box on one of the school's websites that you enter your code in, and it tells you if you are correct or not.

Comment: This is the question:               Write a function named MyFunction, with no return value, it should do just one (1) thing:
Multiply the global variable g_variable by 3 and store the result back into g_variable
You do not have to call MyFunction, or initialize g_variable, I will do that

Comment: @Devin I can help you more, if you edit your question and do a copy&paste of the compiler error. I have no idea what *The error message simply says "sorry, incorrect!" * means, this error message says nothing to me.

Comment: my code:   void myfunction (void)
{
    g_variable = g_variable * 3;
}

Comment: @Devin provided that `g_variable` is a global variable, the code is correct. Again, please post the full error message of the compiler, and please do it in the question, not in the comment section.

Comment: There is no actual error message, I am entering all of this into a box, much like the comment box, and clicking "submit" then, it tells me that my code is incorrect and to try again. I'm going to email the professor, there has to be a problem on the school websites end. Thanks everyone for your time. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Devin ok, then I guess we cannot help you further, without the real error message, we can only guess. Perhaps it's a bug in the system. Did you wrote just the function or do you have to write a whole running program?

Comment: @Devin: The code in this answer includes a `main` routine. The assignment does not say to do that, and statements in it suggest the `main` routine will be provided for you. Likely you are supposed to submit **only** the source code for the `DoSomething` routine. It will be wrapped in a larger source file that supplies a definition of `my_result`, `main`, and other things. You may be getting the error because, since you include `main` in your submission, there are two definitions of it, which is an error. Also, the instructions say to name the routine `DoSomething`, not `dosomething`.

Comment: @Pablo: The problem statement clearly states “You do not have to call `DoSomething`, or initialize `my_result`, I will do that.” `my_result` will not be zero (unless desired) when `DoSomething` is called because it will be given a value by code supplied by the instructor. By adding code to initialize `my_result`, you violate the instructions given.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, I've missed the **do not** part in  *You do not have to call `DoSomething`*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but even after missing the **do not**, what is wrong about my answer that deserved a downvote? I added a complete running program, I think the downvote is unnecessary, it's not me that has to present the homework.

Comment: @Pablo: The assignment is not to provide a complete running program. Your answer goes off on its own path, providing code that was not asked for and that was indicated should not be supplied. It is the **wrong** text to satisfy the instructions. It is not judged by whether it is good or working C code but by whether it conforms to the specification of the problem. It does not. The student needs to submit specific text into grading software, and providing more than what was asked for fails in that software, so it blocks them from completing the assignment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sorry, I don't agree with you in this case. I respect you because you write good answers and leave good comments when my answer have little issues, but in this case I think you are unnecessarily pedantic. I am not the student, I am not the one the one who is doing the homework and Stack Overflow is not a homework service. I saw that the OP wrote the wrong code, so I answered about that, how functions have to be defined and how such a function should look like, I added a **valid** and **correct** C program to show how it should be done ...

Comment: @EricPostpischil it's the OP's job to comply with the requirements of the homework platform that the OP uses to submit his/her homework, it's not my and not our job to deliver ready to submit homework to the OP. Fine, leave the downvote, but I think that this totally undeserved in this case.

Comment: If votes are important to you, then here are tips on improving your answer. (a) The answer starts with “Global variables are initialized with 0,…” This is, first, irrelevant, and, second, incorrect. It is incorrect because an object with static storage duration (which includes “global variables”) that have arithmetic type is initialized **by default** to zero. If a non-zero initializer is given, the object is **not** initialized to zero. It is irrelevant because the instructions say the object will be initialized by the instructor, so it will not have the default initialization.

Comment: (b) Answer the question. The question quotes the instructions given and shows code the student attempted. It is clear from the comments that the student has attempted entering more than the code requested, and this is rejected by the submission software. So the answer should address the student’s mistake: The instructions specify to provide X, but you are providing X and Y. Just submit X. If you want to show a main program, fine, but clarify that it is shown just for illustration and is not the code that provides the code requested by the question.

Comment: (c) As for whether it is your job to deliver ready-to-submit homework, there is no issue here of performing the assignment for the student. Explaining that the submission software does not want the entire program, just the isolated function definition described by the instructions is not giving away programming work the student has not attempted on their own. It is just clarifying a miscommunication or misunderstanding.

Comment: An important skill for engineers is konwing how to conform to a specification. You emphasized you provided “a **valid** and **correct** C program.” But if a project leader asked you to write a header file defining X, and you wrote a header file defining X and Y, when Y was already defined elsewhere, it is not a bonus. It fails to compile, it is wrong, and it breaks the software. If a project leader asks you to provide a subroutine, and you provide a `main` routine, it is not a bonus. It fails to link, it is wrong, and it breaks the software. Correct answers conform to the stated goal.

Comment: Normally, I would not vote down for “Here is an answer, **and** here is how you use it in a program.” But you did not do the first part, and, in this case, the second part has prevented the OP from submitting an acceptable solution. It is actually blocking resolution of the assigned exercise. So, the thing you emphasized, “I added a **valid** and **correct** C program,” is a misguided boast. You are asking for credit for something that was harmful in this case.

Comment: @EricPostpischil *If votes are important to you, then here are tips on improving your answer...* it's not that votes are important to me that I'd do anything to get one, it's more than I want to know a specific reason why I get downvoted, either because what I write is wrong or invalid or makes no sense. The reason why **I want** to know that is that I want to improve/fix my answers and give better answers in the feature, that's all. Thanks for pointing out point a), you are right, I removed that part...

Comment: @EricPostpischil as someone who writes code for a living, I do understand about complying to the specification and it's true that in this case, I did not pay attention to the specific phrasing in the assignment (because I focused on the bad function declaration), but I still think that was not my job and the OP's professor must have explained to all students how and what to submit to the platform, so it should have been the OP's responsibility to comply to that specification, not mine. Sure, I should have written only `DoSomething` and later show an example of a whole program.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions read:

- Write a function named DoSomething, with no return value,…

So code for that is:

```
void DoSomething(void)
```

- … it should do just one (1) thing: Multiply the global variable my_result by 5 and store the result back into my_result.

And code for that is:

```
{
    my_result = my_result * 5;
}
```

- You do not have to call DoSomething, or initialize my_result, I will do that.

Done.  The total code requested is:

```
void DoSomething(void)
{
    my_result = my_result * 5;
}
```

You have indicated in your comments that you are submitting this code into some sort of automatic grading/checking software. So that software is designed to accept code that matches the assignment, no more and no less. Quite likely, it puts your code into a file and that compiles a source file that includes the former file with `#include`. That source file defines `my_result` and `main`, so your code should not, or it will cause compilation and/or link errors. You need to submit just the code requested in the instructions.

Notes about your code:

- The instructions say to write a routine named `DoSomething`. You used `dosomething`. These are different in C; the case matters.
- You declared the routine without specifying a return type. The instructions say the instruction has no return value, but that does not mean you should just omit any return type. You should explicitly say there is no return value by using `void` for the return type of the function, as in `void DoSomething(…)`. (For historic reasons, if you omit the return type in a function declaration, it defaults to `int`. Letting the type default like that is old syntax and should be avoided.)
- The instructions did not say whether the routine should take parameters. This is a shortcoming in the instructions. However, `dosomething (my_result)` is incorrect for two reasons. One, `my_result` is described as a global variable, not a parameter. Two, it is the wrong syntax for a parameter declaration. A parameter declaration must have a type, as in `dosomething(int x)`. Since the routine needs no parameters, a proper declaration is `void DoSomething(void)`. (Although there is some possibility the instructor intended `void DoSomething()`, but that would not generally be preferred.)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to get worried about. Relax, it's just part of the process in becoming a good developer.

To solve such problems, first note what the function expects and we want from the function to return.

- Now, in your question, it is given that function would return nothing. So the return type of the function would be void.
- Now, since we have to use a global variable, it means function expects no argument.

Hence, our code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_result;    // Our Global Variable

void doSomething (void)    // Our Function
{
    my_result = my_result * 5;
}

int main()
{
        /* Asking the value of my_result */
    printf("Please enter a value : ");
    scanf("%d", my_result);

    doSomething();

    printf("\nNew value of my_result is : %d\n", my_result);

    return 0;
}
// End of main.
```